# `startx` starting wrong `xinitrc` file

Tags: arch-linux, x11, awesome

I'm on a fresh Arch Linux installation, trying to get the `awesome` window manager to work.

I was setting up `xinit`/`startx` which I've done a hundred times before according to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#Configuration) guide, and went through the motions of creating a new `~/.xinitrc` file (in user `jeremy`'s home directory). The `~/.xinitrc` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec awesome
```

Now I can confirm that `sudo startx ~/.xinitrc` (as user `jeremy`) correctly starts the `awesome` window manager.

**However, the problem I'm having is that `sudo startx` executes (as far as I am aware) the default `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` file, rather than the `~/.xinitrc` in `jeremy`'s home directory.** (I believe this is correct, because three lots of `xterm` show up in default X windows. (I haven't installed `xclock`.))

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why are you running `sudo startx`? Can't you run `startx` as a regular user? Sorry, last time I used startx was around 20 years ago.

Comment: @terdon Without using `sudo`, I get the "Fatal server error" `(EE) xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 1 (Permission denied)`, which made me think I needed to use `sudo`.

Comment: Hang on though, you say you have confirmed that `sudo startx ~/.xinitrc` works, and executes `~/.xinitrc`. What exactly works and what doesn't work?

Comment: My understanding is that starting X as root is a security no-no. As to why it's not reading the *invoking* user's `~/.xinitrc` that's possibly because your sudoers is configured to set `$HOME` to that of the target user (via `always_set_home` for example - equivalent of always running sudo with the `-H` command line option)

Comment: @terdon Yes, `sudo startx ~/.xinitrc` works, but only if I use `sudo`.

Comment: @steeldriver That would make sense. Any idea why I'm getting that fatal server error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was that I logged in as `root` when I first booted up Arch.

Rebooting and logging in as `jeremy` caused `startx` (without the `sudo`) to work for me.